# Ошибка при вызове сервлета Tomcat + spring + hibernate + mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

Который раз уже пересоздаю приложение, появляется одно и то. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Type Exception Report

Message ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue May 29 17:27:46 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue May 29 17:27:46 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1061)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:996)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: Возможно поможет ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167718/3212712) или можно попробовать перенести Application класс в другой пакет...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я искал в гугле, но дело не в версиях. Скорее всего, дело в путях страниц. Я наверное не заметил, что они кое-где одинаковыми были. Сейчас вроде бы начало работать.

Comment: Тогда напишите это в ответ - кому то в будущем может пригодится)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а комментария недостаточно? Вроде бы не прям ответ как ответ, т.к. не уверен в правильности до конца.

Comment: Если начало работать - значит ответ)